# Formula resulting in 0 in cell, but in function window it gives a correct answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to calculate the standard deviantion from a population and was using the STDEV.P function to do this. But when I inserted it into a cell, the resulting answer was 0. When I looked into the Function window, it gave an (more resonable) answer (around 7600).

```
=STDEVPA(IF(Tests!H:H = "Motion",Tests!D:D))
```

How can I make sure the cell also gives the right answer

Sample data:

```
24  1.46791E+12 1.46791E+12 31544   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   Still   2   1   3   2   6
1   1.46729E+12 1.46729E+12 26515   FALSE   FALSE   TRUE    Motion  1   1   1   2   4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using full column references with an array formula¹. Your sample formula was calculating two columns of 1,048,576 rows.

The following will cut the ranges down to the minimum number of rows required. Data starts in row 2.

```
=STDEVPA(IF(Tests!H2:INDEX(Tests!H:H, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))="Motion", Tests!D2:INDEX(Tests!D:D, MATCH(1E+99,D:D ))))
```

Remember to finish with CSE¹. A single matching row **will** return zero.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>